# Is there any clean CSS method to make each letter in a word a different color?

Tags: css, colors

I need a way to allow each letter of a word to rotate through 3 different colors. I know of some not so clean ways I can do this with asp.NET, but I'm wondering if there might be a cleaner CSS/JavaScript solution that is more search engine friendly.

The designer is including [a file like this](http://stlartworks.efficionconsulting.com/Portals/6/Skins/ArtWorks/img/ProgramsHeading.png) for each page. I'd rather not have to manually generate an image for every page as that makes it hard for the non-technical site editors to add pages and change page names.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is some JavaScript.

```js
var message = "The quick brown fox.";
var colors = new Array("#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff"); // red, green, blue

for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++){
  document.write("<span style=\"color:" + colors[(i % colors.length)] + ";\">" + message[i] + "</span>");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

On the server-side you can do this easily enough without annoying search engines AFAIK.

```
// This server-side code example is in JavaScript because that's
// what I know best.
var words = split(message, " ");
var c = 1;
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
   print("<span class=\"color" + c + "\">" + words[i] + "</span> ");
   c = c + 1; if (c > 3) c = 1;
}
```

If you really want dead simple inline HTML code, write client-side Javascript to retrieve the message out of a given P or DIV or whatever based on its ID, split it, recode it as above, and replace the P or DIV's 'innerHTML' attribute.

Comment: My sample code handles the message word by word and the OP wants to do it by character... but you get the point, I hope.

Answer (score 6):

There’s definitely no solution using just CSS, as CSS selectors give you no access to individual letters (apart from `:first-letter`).

Answer (score 1):

> I'd rather not have to manually generate an image for every page

Then generate the image automatically.

You don't specify which server-side technology you're using, but any good one will allow you to manipulate images (or at least call an external image utility)

So the non-technical users would just need to do something like this:

```
<img src="images/redblueyellow.cfm/programs.png" alt="programs"/>
```

And the redblueyellow.cfm script would then either use an existing programs.png or generate a new image with the multiple colours as desired.

I can provide sample CFML or pseudo-code to do this, if you'd like?

Comment: This is my strongest leaning. We're using ASP.NET. Should be pretty easy to do, with caching, performance should be fine, and we get to use whatever font we like.

Comment: Image replacement for text content is fraught with accessibility issues. This is not generally advisable. Go with the clunky but more open <span> solution,

Comment: @annakata @Peter: I think the only accessibility issue with using an image instead of text in this way is that the user can’t resize images like they can text. Although now that all browsers implement zoom (often as the default method of increasing the size of things on a page), I’d argue this is less of an issue. (Though real text would, one images, be more legible when the size increases than a scaled-up image would.)

Comment: @Paul, @Peter: no, the principle accessibility issue is that a picture of text is not text and therefore an issue for screen-reader technology. In addition there are potential colour and contrast issues for the partially sighted and colour-blind, that's just off the top of my head and I'm not even an expert in this stuff.

Comment: @annakata: “the principle accessibility issue is that a picture of text is not text and therefore an issue for screen-reader technology”. Which screen readers don’t read out `alt` text?

Comment: @annakata: (I’m with you on potential contrast issues though. @Peter: users can, at least with some browsers, override a site’s stylesheet, e.g. if the colours don’t provide enough contrast to make text legible. That’s not possible with images, so you’d need to make sure the image works. There’s some testing tools listed [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200709/10_colour_contrast_checking_tools_to_improve_the_accessibility_of_your_design/).)

Comment: @Paul - I didn't say there weren't solutions :P The issue is that text "just works" and image replacement imposes restrictions and requires more consideration because it isn't *correct*.

Comment: About accessibility: also notice that search engines crawlers won't be able to read the text, while if you put it into text, they will be able to read it.