# change First letter of word font size with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-size

Is there a way to select the first letter of each word with either javascript or jQuery?

Im trying to make  tags on my page have the first letter of each word be a bigger font size. Im assuming it involves regular expressions but all i keep finding are things for form validation. I also see a bunch of stuff for capitalizing the first word. I'm trying to change the font size.

Does anyone know if this can be done and how? Thanks.

Comment: hey nevermind everyone. I just found the answer in an earlier post. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021868/changing-the-value-of-the-first-letter-of-each-word

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a styling change, you might be able to get away with pure CSS using [:first-letter](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp).

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bgNP3/1/

Note: I apparently had to make the `span`s into `inline-block`s for the effect to work.

**Update** fixed link to jsfiddle.

Comment: haha, fitting user name.  I think you forgot to hit [save] on your fiddle before posting the link

Comment: Derp!  OK, I wrote a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using:

- [letteringjs](http://letteringjs.com/) its may be a little more complex than what you need tho, or
- you could use this [Is there any clean CSS method to make each
  letter in a word a different color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155584/is-there-any-clean-css-method-to-make-each-letter-in-a-word-a-different-color)