# How to increase height of string first letter in PHPWord

Tags: php, styles, phpword

I am working on document in PHPWord. I have a string like "HELLO". All letters are in capital words and I want to increase the height of my first letter which is H. What style can I use for increase height of my first letter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change First letter of word font size with javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991488/change-first-letter-of-word-font-size-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p>HELLO</p>

<style>
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 200%;
  color: #8A2BE2;
}
</style>
```

Comment: No it will not working on phpword. because css will not work in phpword. it has to be some style parameter in phpword,

Answer (score 0):

For css3 use this code below :

```
/* Selects the first letter of a <p> */
p::first-letter {
font-size: 130%;
}
```

For css2 Use this code:

```
p:first-letter {
font-size: 130%;
}
```

Comment: no it will not work in phpword. give some style parameter for phpword.